# JQuery + Regex: Grouping and Counting

Tags: regex, jquery-plugins, validation

I have been reading and playing with regex used in JQuery, and have got things partially working but don't seem to be tracking on the failing regex.

The specific problem – I think – has to do with 'look[ing]behind'.

Thanks to CodeJockey for the original direction. Here's my updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $.validator.addMethod("lccharReqs", function(value, element) {
 var lc =  /(?=.*[a-z])/;
 return this.optional(element) || lc.test(value);
   }, "Your password should contain at least one lowercase letter!");

   $.validator.addMethod("uccharReqs", function(value, element) { 
 var uc = /(?=.*[A-Z])/;
 return this.optional(element) || uc.test(value);
   }, "Your password should contain at least one uppercase letter!");

   $.validator.addMethod("nccharReqs", function(value, element) {
 var nc = /(?=.*[0-9])/;
 return this.optional(element) || nc.test(value);
   }, "Your password should contain at least one number!");

   $.validator.addMethod("speccharReqs", function(value, element) {
 var sc = /(?<=.*[\!\@\#\$\%\&\?\-\_])/;
 return this.optional(element) || sc.test(value);
   }, "Your password should contain at least one special character!");

   $("#new_noisuf_pwd").validate({
 rules: {
  inf_field_Password: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 8,
    lccharReqs: true,
    uccharReqs: true,
    nccharReqs: true,
    speccharReqs: true
  },
  pwd_confirm : {
    equalTo: "#inf_field_Password"
  }
   },
   messages: {
    inf_field_Password: {
  required: "Please enter a password!",
  minlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters!",
      maxlength: "Your password cannot be more the 12 characters!"
},
pwd_confirm : {
  equalTo: "Your passwords does not match!"
}
   }});
  });
</script>
```

The reason I'm leaning towards the 'lookbehind' is:

Enter aaaaaaaa  - I get the uppercase error...
Enter Aaaaaaaa  - I get the number error...
Enter 1Aaaaaaa  - I get the special character error, **but**
Enter Passw0rd  - I get no error.

Really trying to learn this and have been reading a lot, but I'm stuck.

Thanks!

[original question]
I am using the 'validation' plugin and am adding a method as follows:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("charReqs", function(value, element) {
                    return this.optional(element) || /^(([a-z]{1})([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{1})([\!\@\#\+\-]{1})) *$/.test(value);
                }, "One lowercase letter, one capital letter, one number and one of the characters listed above - please!");
```

1.) Do I have the syntax correct to check for 1 l-c char, 1 u-c char, 1 num and 1 of a list of special chars somewhere in the string:

```
/^ ( ([a-z]{1}) ([A-Z]{1}) ([0-9]{1}) ([\!\@\#\+\-]{1}) ) *$/
```

2.) Am I grouping this correctly?
3.) If not, please explain.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript - look for JavaScript examples (?)

Comment: ok, well part of the reason is that JavaScript Regexp does not support lookbehind, but I can load up this stuff later and see if I can find an expression that works for you

Comment: hey - I don't have much experience with jQuery validator, so I'm treating this as a learning opportunity. I've put what I think is a minimal version of your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWUv5/1/), but I'm not getting any validation response, despite commenting out what I think you indicate is your problem validation code... feel free to edit it to get it somewhat working and I'll take a fresh look again this afternoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### POINT BY POINT ANSWER

1) Not really, no

Your expression specifies a string that begins with exactly one lower case character `[a-z]`, followed by exactly one upper case character`[A-Z]`, followed by exactly one digit `[0-9]`, followed by exactly one of the following characters: `!`, `@`, `#`, `+`, `-`, followed by zero or more spaces, then the end of the string :-/

2) Nope - not grouped correctly

3) More complex explanation: the character classes (`[a-z]`, `[0-9]`, etc) are *correct enough* (though the `{1}` part and escaping `\` characters are redundant. However, you need to have them in what's called a "lookahead" that matches matching *anything* followed by *those characters*.

Instead of saying "match *one of these*"

```
([a-z])
```

You would say essentially "lookahead and see if you can match *any text* followed by *one of these*, then come back"

```
(?=.*[a-z])
```

To match *two* characters somewhere in the string, you would do like this:

```
(?=(.*[a-z]){2})
```

As for the whole expression, to match *one of each* of the characters you were looking for, use this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\!\@\#\+\-])$
```

To require *two or more of each*, you would use the `{#}` notation, like

```
^(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(.*[0-9]){2})(?=(.*[\!\@\#\+\-]){2})$
```

You could also enforce a minimum length (like 10 characters) like

```
^(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(.*[0-9]){2})(?=(.*[\!\@\#\+\-]){2}).{10,}$
```

### HOWEVER

I would recommend separating these out into separate expressions (I'm guessing  something like `jQuery.validator.addMethod("...", function(...){...}, "Reason...").addMethod(...).addMethod(...).etc()` that each tell the user what's missing. So you'd have one looking for lowercase characters, saying "you need a lower case character", then one looking for digits saying "you need a digit", etc...

Also, the special characters there are really restrictive, so I hope you allow some other ones as well (as long as those are provided (?))

and finally... see http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain! xkcd was hilarious!

Comment: So I got this working, or so I thought:

`$.validator.addMethod("speccharReqs", function(value, element){
    var sc = /(?=.*[\!\@\#\$\%\&\?\-\_])/;
    return this.optional(element) || sc.test(value); }, "Your password should contain at least one special character!");`

If I enter less than 8 chars, error...

If I just enter 8 lowercase alpha chars, error...

If I add the uppercase, error...**but**

If I use something like `Passw0rd`, it doesn't display the special char message, which makes me think I don't have the syntax correct or need a 'lookback'...

Comment: I think I found the 'lookbehind'...nope, not tracking.

Comment: @macgregor I'm looking into the issue while also working out my own issues, so I'll try to get back to you soon - it might help if you put all of the working and not working expressions you've settled on in an update to your question, just to make sure we're on the same page

Comment: @macgregor I don't see any issue - it looks like it should correctly validate with that expression (?) I would try testing with `p@ssw0rd` (should trigger the capital letter requirement error), and also rearrange the order you "declare" the validation rules and ensure there isn't some other JavaScript or jQuery error causing one rule/check to not be run on the value - post your entire validation setup call or make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to show what's happening

Comment: CodeJockey mentioning jsfiddle made me think back to the fact I did get this working in jsbin - perfectly! Which leads me back to the mess of a WP install...Thanks CodeJockey